# How to debug OOP Class/Method in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm attempting the canonical pedagogical programming exercise of building a program to simulate a card game.  This is how far I am:

```
 class Card:

     def __init__(self, suit, rank):
         self.suit = suit
         self.rank = rank
         self.card = str(self.suit) + " " + str(self.rank)

 class Deck:

     def __init__(self):
         self.deck = []

     def Deck_Maker(self):
         ranks = range(1, 11) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
         suits = ["Club", "Heart", "Spade", "Diamond"]

         return self.deck.append(Card(suits[0], ranks[0]))
```

Obviously I'm not done, I have to loop over suits and ranks to construct the deck.  However, before continuing I want to check that I'm on track.  To do this I want to print the results after invoking the Deck_Maker method.  I have attempted to do this with the below code...

```
 def __str__(self):
         d = self.deck
         d2 = d.Deck_Maker()
         return str(d2)
```

Unfortunately, `print(Deck().Deck_Maker())` returns `None`.

What am I doing wrong?  More generally, how do programmers poke around within Classes and Methods while they make them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The append method on a list returns None so this is expected. Try splitting up your lines:

```
deck = Deck()
deck.Deck_Maker()
print(deck)
```

or change the method Deck_Maker to be:

```
def Deck_Maker(self):
    ranks = range(1, 11) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
    suits = ["Club", "Heart", "Spade", "Diamond"]
    self.deck.append(Card(suits[0], ranks[0]))
    return self
```

Edit: There is also a problem in your **str** method. When you set d to self.deck you are setting it to be a list. The list doesn't know anything about the method Deck_Maker. Try changing to the method below. This will turn your list into a string. To make it more readable, you will probably also want to add a str method to the card class.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.deck)
```

Comment: It's not needed to return self, caller of Deck_Maker will have it already

Comment: True, that's what I was going for in my first example. I just added it to the 2nd so that print(Deck().Deck_Maker()) would print something

Comment: @ZackGraber thanks for the suggestions.  I tried the first approach and unfortunately, it did not work.  It returns the following error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Deck_Maker'`.  My code is still missing something.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JacobH ah your problem is in __str__.  I will add to the answer to address that.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

One change to `Card` I'd suggest: instead of having an attribute `card`, initialized in `__init__`, remove that last line from `__init__` and add a `__str__` method:

```
class Card():
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.suit) + " " + str(self.rank)
```

Now every `Card` knows how to represent itself as a `str` on demand. You might add a `__repr__` method, instead of or in addition to `__str__`:

```
    def __repr__(self): 
        return 'Card(%s, %s)' % (self.suit, self.rank)
```

**The `Deck` class**

You can also add a `__str__` method to the `Deck` class.

I've renamed the `Deck_Maker` method to `make_Deck`, and I've made it a classmethod, because the name suggests that you mean it to be a "factory method", callable on the `Deck` class rather than on `Deck` instances. The method now does need to return the `Deck` it creates.

I also renamed the `deck` member variable to `cards`, since after all it is a list of Cards, and we will want to use `deck` to refer to Decks :)

Finally, I made the lists of suits and ranks class attributes, rather than locals of `make_Deck`, on the theory that eventually some other method will want to use them. In Python 3, `range` returns an iterable, hence `list()` around it.

A couple of issues: I'm not sure what cards of rank 1 are, given that you have `"A"` for aces; 2 through 11 seems more likely. (Thus, `Deck`s presently have 56 cards :) Also, it will prove awkward to have both `int`s and `str`s as *ranks*: surely you'll want to compare ranks, and this representation will fight you. (Solution: store ranks as `int` only, and convert in `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.) You may want rank comparison to be a Card method. In that case, `_ranks` and `_suits` should be accessible to that class too (module-globals, for example).

But these *rank* and *suit* problems are for another day, and I'll leave the definitions basically unchanged.

```
class Deck():
    _ranks = list(range(1, 11)) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
    _suits = ["Club", "Heart", "Spade", "Diamond"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    @classmethod
    def make_Deck(cls):
        """cls is Deck"""
        deck = cls()    # make a Deck
        for s in cls._suits:
            for r in cls._ranks:
                deck.cards.append(Card(s, r))
        return deck

    # A basic example:
    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join([str(card) for card in self.cards])
```

Now you can use code like the following:

```
>>> deck = Deck.make_Deck()
>>> print(deck)               # calls deck.__str__
```

which prints the `str` representations of all 56 (!) cards in `deck`, comma-separated and all on one line:

```
Club 1, Club 2, Club 3, Club 4, Club 5, Club 6, Club 7, Club 8, Club 9, Club 10, Club J, Club Q, Club K, Club A, Heart 1, Heart 2, Heart 3, Heart 4, Heart 5, Heart 6, Heart 7, Heart 8, Heart 9, Heart 10, Heart J, Heart Q, Heart K, Heart A, Spade 1, Spade 2, Spade 3, Spade 4, Spade 5, Spade 6, Spade 7, Spade 8, Spade 9, Spade 10, Spade J, Spade Q, Spade K, Spade A, Diamond 1, Diamond 2, Diamond 3, Diamond 4, Diamond 5, Diamond 6, Diamond 7, Diamond 8, Diamond 9, Diamond 10, Diamond J, Diamond Q, Diamond K, Diamond A
```

Comment: @Brian0 you're awesome!!

Comment: @JacobH Thank you *very* much :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't sound super smart, but a good debuger, with breakpoints, helps. You can actually see the flow of execution.

The bumpy issues are mro (method resolution order along the inheritance chain), class methods (does the result comes from instance/class), and metaclasses (class that creates class with type). To understand these issues, initialisation and what object provided the result, drop a logging or a print statement in every **init** , and on methods, that says "enters method foo from object baz". This will make things clearer.